# How to set different tab width depending on what section in the file is being edited (in VIM)?

Tags: javascript, vim, jsx

**In VIM**, I'm working on javascript files, where JS code is mixed with JSX. For example:

```
const nodeData = data.node.data;

if (nodeData.lastReadings.length > 0) {
    rows.push(
      <tr key="readings">
        <td>Last readings</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>,
    );

    nodeData.lastReadings.forEach((reading, idx) => {
        if(reading.value > 0) {
            rows.push(
              <tr key={i}>
                <td>{reading.label}</td>
                <td>{reading.value}</td>
                <td>{reading.actions}</td>
              </tr>
            )
        }
    });
}
```

Now, for JS parts, I would like tab width to be 4 spaces, but for JSX parts (this html looking like code) I would like tab width to be 2 spaces. Is there any setting / plugin that would allow me to achieve this?

My VIM version is 8.0.

Comment: I would look into [this syntax plugin](https://github.com/MaxMEllon/vim-jsx-pretty) in combination [with this one](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript). They are both very configurable and have clear-cut syntax groups, so you should be able to easily get what you want.

Comment: Call me crazy, but I’ve started to prefer 2-space indents for almost every language except python.

Answer (score 1):

If the different parts can be identified via distinct *syntax groups*, my [OnSyntaxChange plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4085) allows to set up custom User events that fire when you move onto / off such syntax. You can then define `:autocmd`s to manipulate the `'softtabstop'` and `'shiftwidth'` values according to your preferences.

If there's no existing syntax script that can handle both JS and JSX, my [SyntaxRange plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4168) can assign a different syntax to regions in a buffer. This would require unique patterns to identify the starts / ends of such regions, or be a manual process of invoking its `:SyntaxInclude` command, though.

Comment: Thanks ;-) I had a brief look on that and its not very obvious how to do it. Where there is plugin that is setting the color syntax for JSX in JS, I'm not sure how it all works, as it looks like there are multiple syntax rules applied in the same time. Also, there are different issues like visual selection of multiple regions and indent (shift + > ), doesn't seem to be easy to solve.

Comment: The [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin might help with that. (I maintain an [extended fork](https://github.com/inkarkat/SyntaxAttr.vim).) But yes, deciphering syntax plugins isn't trivial. And you're right about the other limitations; switching the settings only helps with the usual "trivial" editing, not with larger edits.